# How to Get Single value from array to a variable in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

please help here is my code..

```
var vnotice =[];
  var linkhit = "http://"+ipaddress+"/note.php?action=FullNotice&id="+view;
  //alert(linkhit);
    $http.get(linkhit).then(function (response) {
        vnotice = response.data;

        $scope.vnotice = vnotice;

          filename = response.data.file;
    })

alert(filename);
```

Here help me to get filename from array ..
i was trying

var filename = response.data.filename;

but its not working..
please help.

Comment: Put your alert **inside** the callback function. Then read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/, because you're not understanding the principle of asynchronism.

Comment: Also a terrible practice using global variables like the way you are using `filename `